# CSS won't load properly

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying to run a basic test using an external CSS file to color some HTML text but it isn't working. I Have checked the location of the CSS file and the HTML files and they are in the same place.

I Have tried moving the files around so they are in the same place. I have a feeling this is the issue though.

CODE:

```css
h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>This is the title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The HTML file and CSS file are saved under Templates which is a folder created to hold all front end files in my Django project. Could the file path be a reason?

The

### This is the title

isn't changing colour to red as expected.

Comment: Does it work if you put your css directly in a `<style></style>` balise in the `<head></head>` of your DOM ?

Comment: Allright so there is probably a problem with the path of your css file. When you go in your browser devtool on the link `network` do you see your `style.css` with the code inside ?

Comment: @johannchopin figured it out, it was a Django settings issue. Sorry I'm new to posting here so hopefully my questions will make a bit more sense in the future. Link to video if you're interested... https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=168&v=jxX6LOaKyTM

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Solved it.

It was a Django problem, Django requires you to place a directory with the settings.py so it can reference the static files aka the css files.

In settings.py it looks like this, amend your directory to suit:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/Users/benja/WDTimesheetProject01/templates/css/',

]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then in the HTML, at the very top you place:

```
{% loadstatic %}
```

Which gives you the final file with correctly loaded css:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is the title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting your browser or event testing it on a different browser; I had this kinda problem a couple of time and that was my way out